# How can I make this editbutton works?

Tags: javascript

I am currently doing a to do list for learning, but now im stuck in a simple step, when I put a prompt everything works fine but when a change it for a swal.fire input I can't make it work. Please I need some help with this, I search everywhere and I can't get the answer.
I been trying to make for the past 3 days but I can't comprehend the problem.

```js
const input = document.querySelector ("#inputText");
const list = document.querySelector ("#list");
const addBtn = document.querySelector ("#addTexto");

let listNum = 0;


// Funcion principal
const filtroList = (x) => {
    const valorMinimo = 3;
    if (x) {
        if (x.length > valorMinimo) {
            return x;
        } else {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'ERROR',
                text: 'Ingrese 3 o más caracteres!',
                position: 'top',
                timer: 2000,
                background: '#eaf6f6',
                width: '20%'
            })
        }
    }
};

//Llamar evento
addBtn.addEventListener ('click', () => {
    let inputText = filtroList(input.value);
    
    if (inputText) {
        list.innerHTML += `<li class="my-3 py-4 shadow list-group-item bg-white" id="list${listNum}">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                <input class="" type="checkbox" id="check${listNum}" onclick="chkbx(${listNum})">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <span class=" h4" id="text${listNum}"> ${inputText} </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <button class=" btn btn-dark" onclick="borrarText(${listNum})">Borrar</button>
                    <button class=" btn btn-dark" onclick="editarText(${listNum})">Editar</button>
                </div>                  
                </div>    
                </li>`;
        input.value = "";
        listNum++;
    }
} );

//Funcion chk
const chkbx = (e) => {
    const checkbox = document.getElementById(`check${e}`);
    const nueva = document.getElementById(`text${e}`);
    const classExit = nueva.classList.contains("text-decoration-line-through");
    if (classExit == true) {
        nueva.classList.remove("text-decoration-line-through");
    } else {
        nueva.classList.add("text-decoration-line-through");
    }
};

//Funcion edit
const editarText = (e) => {
    const nuevoText = document.getElementById(`text${e}`);
    
    const newText = Swal.fire({
        title: 'Ingrese nuevo texto',
        input: 'text',
        inputPlaceholder: 'Nuevo Texto...'
    })

    // const newText = prompt("");
    if (filtroList(newText)) {
        nuevoText.innerHTML = newText;
    }
};


//Funciton borrar
const borrarText = (e) => {
    const current = document.getElementById(`text${e}`).innerHTML;
    
    if (borrarText) {
        const p = document.getElementById("list");
        const c = document.getElementById(`list${e}`);
        p.removeChild(c);
        Toastify({
            text: "ELIMINADO",
            duration: 3000,
            style: {
                background: "linear-gradient(to right, #F05F57, #360940)",
            },
            }).showToast();
    }
};


// DarkMode masomenos xD
const darkMode = document.querySelector (".checkbox");
const body = document.querySelector ("body");
const cont = document.querySelector (".bg-white");
const btn = document.querySelector (".btn-dark");
const toDo = document.querySelector (".border-dark");
const titlo = document.querySelector (".h1")

darkMode.onclick = () => {
    body.classList.toggle ('dark');
    titlo.classList.toggle ('h12');

    cont.classList.toggle ('bg-dark');
    cont.classList.toggle ('bg-white');

    btn.classList.toggle ('btn-danger');
    btn.classList.toggle ('btn-dark');

    toDo.classList.toggle ('border-dark');
    toDo.classList.toggle ('border-danger');
}
```

```css
.checkbox {
    opacity: 0;
}

.label {
    background-color: #111;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    left: 150px;
    top: -32px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    height: 26px;
    width: 50px;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

.label .ball {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

.checkbox:checked + .label .ball {
    transform: translateX(24px);
}


.fa-moon {
    color: #817a5e;
}

.fa-sun {
    color: #f39c12;
}

.darkMode * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(214, 230, 245);
}

#darkMode {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px #cecece,
                inset -4px -4px -6px white ;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    transform: scale(.7);
    background-color: blueviolet;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px crimson;
}

.h12{
    color: white;
}

.div-dm{
    background-color: rgb(37, 37, 51);
    }

.row-dk {
    background-color: black;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body.dark {
    background: #292C35;
}

.hr {
    background-color: rgb(124, 124, 124);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="List.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js/src/toastify.min.css">
    <title>Lista/Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="container rounded-3 border border-2 border-dark my-5 bg-white" style="height:auto;" id="div">
        <div class="div1">
            <h1 class='h1'>Lista/Todo List</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-8">
                    <input class="py-3 form-control shadow" placeholder="Ingrese texto" type="text" id="inputText">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <button class="mt-2 btn btn-dark" id="addTexto">Añadir</button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
                    <label class="label" for="chk">
                        <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
                        <div class="ball"></div>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="hr">
        <div class="row rounded bg-whitee">
            <div class=" col-12">
                <ul class=" list-group" id="list"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <Script src="List.js"></Script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your question looks good, but it is hard for readers to mix up English and Spanish. Please provide code examples with unified English texts.

Comment: so  what is the issue you're facing ? you didn't tell!